# Conversion of a record towards JSON containing a time:Time type (or any other object type)

Tags: ballerina

in development of an application with Ballerina, I am using the record type to define an 'Event' data structure.

```
public type Event record {
    string eventType;
    time:Time eventTime;
};
```

When converting an Event record towards JSON and vise-versa, what should I expect on the conversion of non simple values towards JSON?

What I experience is that an string representation of the object internal field structure is produced as output. 
I actually expected that on conversion to JSON, the time.toString() method would be called. Is this behavior intentionally and can I influence this behavior?

Regards Rob

```
------ actual output --------------------------
2018-08-31 17:21:51,865 INFO  [] - {"eventType":"OrderAccepted", "eventTime":{"time":1535742000000, "zone":{"zoneId":"+02:00", "zoneOffset":7200}}}  

------ expected output ------------------------
2018-08-31 17:21:51,865 INFO  [] - {"eventType":"OrderAccepted", "eventTime": "2018-08-31T21:00:00+02:00"}
```

Ballerina code used:

```
import ballerina/log;
import ballerina/time;

function main(string... args) {
    json je = testTimeToJson();
    log:printInfo(je.toString());
}

function testTimeToJson() returns json {
    Event event = {};
    event.eventType = "OrderAccepted";
    event.eventTime = time:createTime(2018, 8, 31, 21, 0, 0, 0, "+02:00");
    return check <json>event;
}

public type Event record {
    string eventType;
    time:Time eventTime;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intentional because during object to json or record to json conversion, the public fields are converted to json key value pairs. The  `time:createTime` method returns a `Time` object in Ballerina, the definition of which can be viewed in the following location:

https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/blob/62ace431ac7d0645d117072216adc70eb16911d6/stdlib/time/src/main/ballerina/time/timelib.bal#L36

When it is converted to json its public fields are converted to key value pairs. Recursively public fields of `Timezone` are also converted to key value pairs based on its public fields.

This behavior is consistent with json to record/map conversion.

It is not possible to alter the behaviour of object to json conversion at the moment. You can request for this feature [here](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the intended way. This enables the access individual components of your time since it is of type time and not string.

If you need a string, your field should be a string type field and it's value can be populated using time.toString() method